# check whether number is odd or even using getters and setters

Tags: java, methods

*this method is working but not showing odd numbers*

```
public class OddEvan_checker {

    private int number;

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        number = number;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public int calculate() {

        if (number % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println(number+"even");

        } else {
            System.out.println("odd ");

        }
        return number;
    }
}
```

Comment: You only print out `"odd"` in the else. Change it to `System.out.println(number + " odd");`

Comment: Neither the getter nor the setter checks if the number is odd or even.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class OddEvenChecker {  // Also consider renaming the typo and avoiding snake_case
    private int number;
    public void setNumber(int number) {
        number = number;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public int calculate() {
        if (number % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println(number+"even");
        } else {
            System.out.println(number+"odd ");  // add the number here to solve the issue
        }
        return number;
    }
}
```

Comment: System.out.println(" enter number");
        OddEvan_checker hello = new OddEvan_checker();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);   
        
        hello.setNumber(input.nextInt());
        System.out.println(hello.calculate()); main method